# "No shape named intersection-1 is known" error in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, loops

I want to draw a circle with arrows ending not perpendicular but straight on the surface. I managed so far to draw the paths I need and I already read about the naming of paths, but I get an error as soon as I change the draw command to `\path` and uncomment the commented line for the arrows in my code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%
\draw[name path global/.expanded=circle] (0,0) circle (3);
%
\foreach \x  in {-3.5,-3,...,3.5}
 {
  \draw [name path global/.expanded=line\x] (\x,3.5) -- (\x,-3.5);
%  \draw[->, name intersections={of=circle and line\x}] (\x,3.5)--(intersection-1);
    }
%
%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

What do I have to change so the naming within the loop works out?

Comment: The outer two lines do not intersect the circle hence the error about the nonexistence of `(intersection-1)`. The interval `{-3,-2.5,...,3}` works.

Comment: *blush* thx, that worked out.